# How can I find the first indirect parent

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So imagine the following:

```
Company A is owned by Company B { intermediate = true } 
which is owned by Company C { intermediate = false } 
which is owned by Company D { intermediate = false }
```

Given that I'm at "Company A" I want to get to "Company C" without returning "Company D"

(I want the first Company that isn't a intermediate.)

There's also the following scenario:

```
Company Foo is owned by Company Bar { intermediate = false }
Company Foo is owned by Company Baz { intermediate = true }
Company Baz is owned by Company Das { intermediate = false }
```

In this case, it should return both "Company Bar" and "Company Das" because they're both owners of "Company Foo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH p = (:Company {name: "Foo"})-[:IS_OWNED_BY*]->(first:Company {intermediate: false})
WHERE NONE(n IN NODES(p)[1..-1] WHERE NOT n.intermediate)
RETURN first
```

The `WHERE` clause tests that none of the nodes in between the start and end nodes have a `false` `intermediate` value.

Note: If there can be many long `IS_OWNED_BY` paths, you should consider putting a reasonable upper bound on the variable-length relationship pattern to avoid taking too long or running out of memory. For example, `[:IS_OWNED_BY*..6]`.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks—could you explain what that [1...-1] means? I mean...the whole "WHERE" part of the query.

Comment: Added a brief explanation to my answer.